# Error #1502: A script has executed for longer than the default time period of 15 seconds

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

this is my first time using AS3 so I apologise if the cause of this problem is painfully obvious.

I'm making chess and I've got a class for each piece on the board. When it's player 1's turn, all the black pieces should wait to be clicked, but when I implement this it returns error #1502.

```
package chess.sprites{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class BlackBishop extends MovieClip{

    public function BlackBishop(){
        trace("bb created");
    }

    public function waitForClick(){
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, myTurn);
    }

    protected function myTurn(me:MouseEvent){
        trace("Clicked");
    }

}

}
```

The function waitForClick() in BlackBishop is being called by another class like this.

```
public function setBlackTurn(){
        for(var i:int = 0;i < 8;i++){
            blackPawn[i].waitForClick();
        }
        for(var i:int = 0;i < 2;i++){
            blackRook[i].waitForClick();
            blackKnight[i].waitForClick();
            blackBishop[i].waitForClick();
        }
        blackQueen.waitForClick();
        blackKing.waitForClick();
    }
```

I've been reading up a lot on error #1502 but it seems it only happens when I add the listener in BlackBishop. Any ideas?

Game class:

```
package chess{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import chess.sprites.*;

public class Game extends MovieClip{

    //Contains all sprite classes
    public var blackPawn:Array = new Array(8);
    public var blackRook:Array = new Array(2);
    public var blackKnight:Array = new Array(2);
    public var blackBishop:Array = new Array(2);
    public var blackQueen:BlackQueen;
    public var blackKing:BlackKing;

    public var whitePawn:Array = new Array(8);
    public var whiteRook:Array = new Array(2);
    public var whiteKnight:Array = new Array(2);
    public var whiteBishop:Array = new Array(2);
    public var whiteQueen:WhiteQueen;
    public var whiteKing:WhiteKing;

    public var boardArray:Array = new Array(64);

    //Adds sprites to stage
    public function addSprites(){
        var spacing:int = 46;

        for(var i:int = 0;i < 8;i++){
            blackPawn[i] = new BlackPawn();
            blackPawn[i].x = 112 + (spacing * i); //Sets x-pos of sprite
            blackPawn[i].y = 316; //Sets y-pos of sprite
            addChild(blackPawn[i]); //Adds sprite to stage

            whitePawn[i] = new WhitePawn();
            whitePawn[i].x = 112 + (spacing * i);
            whitePawn[i].y = 362 - (spacing * 6);
            addChild(whitePawn[i]);
        }

        for(i = 0;i < 2;i++){
            blackRook[i] = new BlackRook();
            blackRook[i].x = 112 + (spacing * 7 * i);
            blackRook[i].y = 362;
            addChild(blackRook[i]);

            blackKnight[i] = new BlackKnight();
            blackKnight[i].x = 158 + (spacing * 5 * i);
            blackKnight[i].y = 362;
            addChild(blackKnight[i]);

            blackBishop[i] = new BlackBishop();
            blackBishop[i].x = 204 + (spacing * 3 * i);
            blackBishop[i].y = 362;
            addChild(blackBishop[i]);

            whiteRook[i] = new WhiteRook();
            whiteRook[i].x = 112 + (spacing * 7 * i);
            whiteRook[i].y = 362 - (spacing * 7);
            addChild(whiteRook[i]);

            whiteKnight[i] = new WhiteKnight();
            whiteKnight[i].x = 158 + (spacing * 5 * i);
            whiteKnight[i].y = 362 - (spacing * 7);
            addChild(whiteKnight[i]);

            whiteBishop[i] = new WhiteBishop();
            whiteBishop[i].x = 204 + (spacing * 3 * i);
            whiteBishop[i].y = 362 - (spacing * 7);
            addChild(whiteBishop[i]);
        }

        blackQueen = new BlackQueen();
        blackQueen.x = 112 + (spacing * 3);
        blackQueen.y = 362;
        addChild(blackQueen);

        blackKing = new BlackKing();
        blackKing.x = 112 + (spacing * 4);
        blackKing.y = 362;
        addChild(blackKing);

        whiteQueen = new WhiteQueen();
        whiteQueen.x = 112 + (spacing * 3);
        whiteQueen.y = 362 - (spacing * 7);
        addChild(whiteQueen);

        whiteKing = new WhiteKing();
        whiteKing.x = 112 + (spacing * 4);
        whiteKing.y = 362 - (spacing * 7);
        addChild(whiteKing);
    }

    public function resetArray(){
        //Reset all values in array
        for (var i:int = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            boardArray[i] = false;
        }

        //Set appropriate values in array for starting positions
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            boardArray[i] = true;
            boardArray[i + 8] = true;
            boardArray[i + (8 * 6)] = true;
            boardArray[i + (8 * 7)] = true;
        }
    }

    //Tells all black pieces to wait to be clicked
    public function setBlackTurn(){
        for(var i:int = 0;i < 8;i++){
            blackPawn[i].waitForClick();
        }
        for(i = 0;i < 2;i++){
            blackRook[i].waitForClick();
            blackKnight[i].waitForClick();
            blackBishop[i].waitForClick();
        }
        blackQueen.waitForClick();
        blackKing.waitForClick();
    }

    public function setWhiteTurn(){
        for(var i:int = 0;i < 8;i++){
            whitePawn[i].waitForClick();
        }
        for(i = 0;i < 2;i++){
            whiteRook[i].waitForClick();
            whiteKnight[i].waitForClick();
            whiteBishop[i].waitForClick();
        }
        whiteQueen.waitForClick();
        whiteKing.waitForClick();
        }

    }

}
```

Code in frame:

```
import chess.*;

var turn:int = 1;//1 is black, 2 is white
var gameRunning:Boolean = false;

var game:Game = new Game();
addChild(game);
game.addSprites();
game.resetArray();
gameRunning = true;

while(gameRunning){
    if(turn == 1){
        game.setBlackTurn();
    }else if(turn == 2){
        game.setWhiteTurn();
    }else{

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything that would cuase a 1502.  Are you sure there isn't something else going on?  Share more code maybe.   As an aside, would probably be better to just  `mouseEnable = false;` all your black pieces when not black's turn instead of adding the same listener over and over.

Comment: I changed my code to use the mouseEnabled function like you said, and  that actually solves a problem I knew I would run into later :)

Even when I use that I'm getting 1502 though. I can show you the code in my main Game class and also the code in the frame if you think it would help.

Comment: Please include the code that creates and fills those arrays. Thank you.

Comment: I've edited the the post to include all the code you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue lies here:

```
gameRunning = true;

while(gameRunning){
    ....
}
```

That while loop will lock the thread until `gameRunning` equals false.  Which likely doesn't happen within 15 seconds. (I don't think it happens ever based of the code you've shared)

You're likely used to other languages that use a game loop.  In AS3, a game loop needs to be done in an enter frame handler, or a timer tick.

What is happening by the looks of the code, is that over and over and over your are toggling the turn, and you are doing so in a loop that is running as fast as it can and will lock the UI.

Take out that `while` loop.  I don't see how you need it anyway.  You want to change turns after a player moves a piece.

---

Here is a tip on how to architect this application:

1. Make a base class that every piece extends.  This way you won't have to make redundant code.   So make a class called `ChessPiece` and make it extend `MovieClip` (or `Sprite` if you pieces don't use the timeline).  Then have all your pieces extend that `ChessPiece` class. Now they will all have whatever function and vars you've defined in the base class (`ChessPiece`).
2. When you change turns, simply lock mouse events on the pieces that belong to the other color.  This could be really easy if you made two containers:

   ```
    var blackContainer:Sprite = new Sprite(); 
    addChild(blackContainer);

    var whiteContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
    addChild(whiteContainer);

    //then in your for loops where you create your pieces, add them to the appropriate container
    blackContainer.addChild(blackPawn[i]);

    //then you can do this when the turn changes to white:
    blackContainer.mouseChildren = false;  //now none of the pieces can dispatch mouse events / be clicked
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) This solved the 1502 problem. When I use 

`blackContainer.addChild()`

would that be as well as the addChild() that's already used to add the pieces to the stage, or instead of it?

Comment: Instead of.  an item can only have one parent, so if you did both, it would end up the child whatever the last thing you added it to was.

Comment: Alright thanks :) I definitely will accept it. I just didn't want to yet because I wasn't sure if I'd still be able to comment if I did.